# jquery-ui slider: passing current value to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using the jquery-ui slider. I would like to pass the current value of the slider to a function every time there is a change, but I'm not sure how to?

```
// jquery ui slider
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  value: 2,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $("#amount").val( ui.value );
  }
});
$("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider( "value" ) );
```

});

```
function skillLevel(){
// do something based upon slider value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the library, but it seems, that `slide` is called each time the slider changes it's value.  Within slide you are able to access `value` and call your own function like this:

```
slide : function(event, ui) {
  skillLevel(ui.value);
}
```

or alternatively:

```
slide : function(event, ui) {
    skillLevel(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

```
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
  value: 2,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $("#amount").val( ui.value );
  },
    change: skillLevel
});
$("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider( "value" ) );

function skillLevel(){
// do something based upon slider value

};
```

**[TEST](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v6pkgsyd/)**